# How to show images on an RDLC report

Tags: .net-3.5, reportviewer, rdlc

I have an RDLC report and would like one of the columns in a table on this report to display images.  The datasource for my report is a class that has a property called Image of type `System.Drawing.Image`.

On my report I dragged an image control onto the column and I set the following properties:

```
MIMEType:  image/png
Source:  Database
Value:  =Fields!Image.Value
```

When I run my report, I get a broken image.

I'd really appreciate any suggestions!

Thanks in advance :o)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but I got it to work.  It looks like the problem was in using System.Drawing.Image.

In my class, I created a new property called ImageByte of type byte[].  I didn't make a setter for ImageByte, but I made a getter that does the following:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
return ms.ToArray();
```

I updated my report to have =Fields!ImageByte.Value for the Value and now everything appears to be working as expected :o)

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you take a new Form in your project on Load event you Wright this line below:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
```

After that take reportViewer on that page and set smart tag of that, choose Design a new report and take an image control on it from ToolBox, set its property

```
Source = External Value = file:\D:Images\Sunset.jpg
```

**Note: Image(Sunset.jpg) saved in Images folder on D drive. You changed it according to your requirement.**